# Excel copy cell value to another cell if cell value changes

Tags: excel, function

I am planning to prepare a graph based on a display board raw data.

now problem is raw data keeps on updating once production is producing a part say 2 to 3, 3 to 4 & so on..

I want to copy the cell value to another cell to have the data for graph.
So whenever cell value updates excel will copy the last or current value to another sheet.

Pls help if you understand the requirement.

Comment: Can you provide some more specific information? Where is your input data? Is it in the same Workbook as the data that will be referenced for the graph, or is it in a different file? Have you considered using a cell reference?

Comment: same file or different file...both are okay..refer will copy the current value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer in other site, & its working properly,

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date

Sub ValueStore()
Dim dTime As Date
    Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A1").Value
    Call StartTimer
End Sub


Sub StartTimer()
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
End Sub<code>
```

after the code I have created 2 command buttons for timer start & stop.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you want to copy some data from a cell to another cell (or cells) to fix the date for your graph.  How about putting something similar to this code in your Worksheet Change Event.  I assumed we're copying a value from E3 to G3.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Copy value from E3 to G3 when E3 changes

Cells(3, 7).Value = Cells(3, 5).Value


End Sub
```

This is my first post so sorry if I didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: You have understood the things very well...but i tried using this code...but not working...could you please elaborate how to use it properly..

Comment: In the VBA editor (Alt + F11 to load it), open the Projects Explorer (Ctrl + R). Find your workbook in the Projects Explorer and double-click the sheet in which you want the code to run.  You can now paste the above code into the right hand code window.  You will need to amend the cell addresses I used in the example (E3 & G3) to whatever cells you are using.

Comment: Thank you...it worked...i was not sure about the (Cells(3, 7).Value = Cells(3, 5).Value) 5 & 7 denoted columns...but my requirement is to keep the change also...so only one time 3,7 will update next time, after that, 4,7,  5,7,  6,7 & so on...any idea how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay, this needs some error handling but might provide the next step. H3, i.e. Cells(3, 9), is used as a row counter incremented by 1 each time the value in E3 is changed. Start of with 3 in H3

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Integer

' Copy value from E3 to G3 when E3 changes, use H3 as row marker/counter

If Target = Cells(3, 5) Then

    c = Cells(3, 9).Value

    Cells(c, 7).Value = Cells(3, 5).Value

    Cells(3, 9).Value = c + 1

Else

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you "gaz" for your reply. I got these code from some other post....its working fine only if i press enter in main cell...automatically its not updating... `code` Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then

        ' Get the last row on our destination sheet (using Sheet2, col A here)...
        Dim intLastRow As Long
        intLastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Add our value to the next row...
        Sheet2.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "A") = Target.Value

    End If

End Sub